# Como criar um checkbox que não possa ser alterado o valor (readonly)

Tags: html, checkbox, input

Gostaria de fazer com que o checkbox não seja alterado (readonly).

Comment: è isso que você precisa? https://jsfiddle.net/r5wpandw/

Comment: Poste o código seu. Aproveite e faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender mais a respeito do site.

Comment: isso @miltoncamara! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CarlosHenrique, você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled> Checkbox
```

Note que inclui o atributo disabled no input.

Segue um link de exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/r5wpandw/

Answer (score 0):

**Através do Javascript**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(
  node => node.onclick = function() {
    return false;
  }
)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk" checked>
```